# Cron jobs not working as expected

Tags: debian, cron

I have setup 3 crontab jobs to execute my simple ruby scripts periodically  every minute, 5 minutes and hour. They execute, however they do not do anything. I have only one user on the machine (`root`)  and I have setup the crontab by executing the command `crontab -e`. `crontab -l` lists my current crontab jobs:

```
5 * * * * ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/cpu_check.rb
0 * * * * ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/free_disk_space.rb
1 * * * * ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/free_ram_check.rb
```

I can see that they execute but not in the right intervals and also they do not do anything whereas if I execute those ruby files manually they work perfectly fine. I can confirm that the ruby programs work fine 100%, they pass tests, etc. Here are the crontab logs:

```
Dec  6 15:45:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28281]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec  6 15:55:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28478]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec  6 16:00:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28584]: (root) CMD (ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/free_disk_space.rb)
Dec  6 16:01:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28614]: (root) CMD (ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/free_ram_check.rb)
Dec  6 16:05:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28702]: (root) CMD (ruby /root/www/server-monitoring/current/tasks/cpu_check.rb)
Dec  6 16:05:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[28703]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec  6 16:15:01 monitoring-jedrzej CRON[29214]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Full path to ruby maybe? Like /usr/bin/ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set these jobs to run every minute, every 5 minutes, and every hour.  All three are set to run once per hour, at :01 past the hour, :05 past the hour, and :00 past the hour.  Instead you might try something like

```
* * * * *    echo 'run every minute'
*/5 * * * *  echo 'run every 5 minutes'
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *   echo 'alternate every-five-minute'
0 * * * *    echo 'run every hour on the hour'
```

Comment: Oh stupid me...I totally missed this. Thank yo uso much! You've made my day!

Comment: I have accidently found a note on RVM site that 'For every installed ruby and created gemset RVM creates wrappers for basic command line tools like gem, rake, ruby' and I should actually do this: `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0/ruby /path/to/script.rb` and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'll find that this is an environment issue.  Running a script from cron does NOT execute the `/etc/profile` script.  You can source `/etc/profile` at the start of the script, or set just those variables that you'll need for your script (`PATH` is one that comes quickly to mind).

I'd suggest creating a small script that runs the `env` command and pipe that to a file so that you can see exactly what your environment is when running something from cron.  Should help you find what is not set that needs to be.

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed that they do not run at the right intervals. The first job should run every 5 mintues, the second job every hour and the last one every mintue, however, as you can see in the logs, they do not execute in the right interval. Any ideas?

Comment: I hadn't looked at that.  The minute in crontab is what minute of the hour to execute that script, not how many minutes apart.  You should be able to add a comma separated list of minutes (00,05,10,15, ...) to get it to do what you want, but that gets tedious.  Looking into it a little, I see that you should be able to do */5 for every five minutes, */2 for every two minutes, and */1 for every minute.